# Python: Recursion to count up an array of size n

Tags: python, recursion

I am struggling about a recursion problem, which should not be too hard, but for some reason I don't come up with a solution.

I have an array of size "n" and I want to count up each element from 0 to n in a way that I get each possible combination.

```
n = 3
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
[...  ]
[3,3,3]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please mark it as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: How? The `homework` tag is not to be used anymore. Questions, even those about homework, need to stand on their own without being too localized or requiring us to pussyfoot around the solution.

Comment: No, it is not my homework. I left school 10 years ago :D.

Comment: I assume you cannot use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` and then rotate to obtain all the possible permutations?

Comment: @Fritz: Why the requirement for recursion then?

Comment: @NedBatchelder I did not know about the itertools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for (explicit) recursion:

```
import itertools
for comb in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=3):
    print comb
```

produces:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
...
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not know about the function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to code it up yourself, and have to use recursion:

```
def gen(n, l, prefix=()):
  if l == 0:
    print prefix
  else:
    for i in range(n):
      gen(n, l - 1, prefix + (i,))

gen(4, 3)
```

Comment: I guess I will go with the itertools solution, but thanks good to see what I was trying to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that makes the procedure very explicit:

```
def combinations(n, elements = None):
    if elements == 0: return [[]]

    if not elements: elements = n

    result = []
    for v in range(n + 1):
        for subcombination in combinations(n, elements - 1):
            result.append([v] + subcombination)

    return result
```

There are more pythonic ways to do it that might have better performance, including comprehensions or generators, but it sounds like you're looking for an explicit implementation.